# change class to fuction Component

Tags: reactjs, function, class

I try to convert this React Class Component to a Function Component
this is the main class Component code I have it working fine

```
import React from "react";
import * as BooksAPI from "./BooksAPI";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

;

and I convert and become like this But it give me an error
(this is the code when i change the class to function but it doesn't work

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import * as BooksAPI from "./BooksAPI";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: Your useEffect function isn’t closed. The variables local to the component should be declared.

Comment: thank for your answer, But can you explain little more I am new in react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### please try this code

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import * as BooksAPI from "./BooksAPI";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./components/Home";
import Search from "./components/Search";

function BooksApp() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    showSearchPage: false,
    books: [],
    search: "",
    booksFromSearch: [],
    loadSearch: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    BooksAPI.getAll().then((res) => {
      setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        books: res,
      }));
    });
  }, []);

  const handleBooksSearch = async (search) => {
    await BooksAPI.search(search).then((res) => {
      if (res && !res.error) {
        setState(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          booksFromSearch: res.map((booksSearch) => {
            prevState.books.forEach((book) => {
              if (booksSearch.id === book.id) booksSearch.shelf = book.shelf
            })
            return booksSearch;
          }),
          loadSearch: true,
        }));
      } else {
        setState(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          booksFromSearch: `No books like: " ${state.search} "`,
          loadSearch: false,
        }))
      }
    }); // then
    console.log("Search");
    console.log(state.booksFromSearch);
  };


  const changeShelf = async (book, shelf) => {
    await BooksAPI.update(book, shelf);
    await BooksAPI.getAll().then((res) => {
      setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        books: res,
      }));
    });
    handleBooksSearch(state.search)
  };

  const handleSearch = async (event) => {
    await setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      search: event.target.value,
    }));
    console.log(state.search);
    handleBooksSearch(state.search);
  };

  return (
      <Router>
        <div className="app">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/search">
              <Search
                  handleSearch={handleSearch}
                  search={state.search}
                  booksFromSearch={state.booksFromSearch}
                  changeShelf={changeShelf}
                  loadSearch={state.loadSearch}
              />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
              <Home books={state.books} changeShelf={changeShelf} />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default BooksApp;
```

Comment: Thanks you that was grate, you save me. :)